# Extract value from Maybe in do block

Tags: haskell

Hi I have a piece of code where I retrieving a `Maybe User` where `User` is my own type.

```
getUserById :: Int -> IO (Maybe User)
getUserById id = let userId = id in do
            conn <- createConnection
            (columnDef, inputStream) <- query conn selectByIdQuery [One $ MySQLInt32 (intToInt32 userId)]
            maybeMySQLValue <- Streams.read inputStream
            return (transformToUser <$> maybeMySQLValue)
```

But the key is that the function that call this functions expect a `IO User` and not a `IO Maybe User`

> getUserById :: Int -> IO  User

Any advice about how to extract in the do block the value from the Maybe?
I´m trying this but still does not work

```
 user <- extractMaybeUser (transformToUser <$> maybeMySQLValue)
            return user

extractMaybeUser :: Maybe User -> User
extractMaybeUser maybeUser = case maybeUser of
     Just value -> value
     Nothing -> User 1 "default User"
```

Regards

Comment: What is supposed to happen if you get `Nothing`?

Comment: I did a piece of code about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
user <- extractMaybeUser (transformToUser <$> maybeMySQLValue)
```

The reason why this code might not work is that `extractMaybeUser` has return type of `User`:

```
extractMaybeUser :: Maybe User -> User
```

There is no monadic value to extract from using `<-`, so what about just wrapping in `IO` the user we get from `extractMaybeUser`?

```
return (extractMaybeUser (transformToUser <$> maybeMySQLValue))
```

It will at least have `IO User` type

Comment: I will check later, but I tried your solution before but without the parentheses, which in Haskell as usual always makes the difference 

Comment: @paul yea, without parentheses it behaves differently. If you have the expression `f g 2` and want to apply the result of `g 2` to `f`, then you need to write it as `f (g 2)` or `f $ g 2`

Comment: I learn the $ recently and is quite handy. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Another way to put this same answer is this: Writing `user <- extractMaybeUser ...` implies that `extractMaybeUser ...` is an `IO` action that produces a user.  Instead, `extractMaybeUser` is just a function, so the right statement to bind its result in a `do` block is `let user = extractMaybeUser ...`